# Word order: already had been or had already been...?

Tags: grammar

Here is the sentence from a New York Times article:

"...and three women whos homes already had been feng shui-ed by our instructor..."

Could the words 'already' and 'had' been flipped in this case? Why or why not? I am just trying to understand this a bit more.

Thanks!

Comment: This is more of an english question, less about writing.

Comment: Hi Yousuf, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn about our site. Questions about grammar and word order are off-topic for our site, but are accepted at [English.SE]. I've gone ahead and migrated your question so you can get an answer. Good luck and happy writing!